# calculate difference between dates and add column for the result in data frame R

Tags: r

I searched for a solution to my specific problem but I didn't find a conclusion.

I have a dataframe which looks like

```
ID1  |   ID2 |     Date   |
 1   |   a   |  01/02/2018|
 1   |   b   |  03/05/2018|
 1   |   c   |  20/08/2018|
 2   |   ee  |  02/11/2017|
 2   |   ff  |  18/11/2017|
```

I want to calculate the difference between dates for each ID. 
For example for `ID=1` I would like to have a column with the number of days: 91 (difference between 03/05/2018 and 01/02/2018) and 109 (difference between 20/08/2018 and 03/05/2018).

My dataframe contains 4500 rows and the ids can be duplicated more than 2 times.

I have already worked with `diff_date` to calculate the difference between dates in different columns.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be done with a `group_by` difference (`diff`).  Before that, we need to change the 'Date' to `Date` class (`dmy` - lubridate - based on the order of day, month, year)

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Date = dmy(Date)) %>%
    group_by(ID1) %>%
    mutate(Diff = c(NA, diff(Date)))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   ID1 [2]
#    ID1 ID2   Date        Diff
#  <int> <chr> <date>     <dbl>
#1     1 a     2018-02-01    NA
#2     1 b     2018-05-03    91
#3     1 c     2018-08-20   109
#4     2 ee    2017-11-02    NA
#5     2 ff    2017-11-18    16
```

Comment: I think the dmy function is not working for me, I have only NA. I tried to change the class from character  to "Date" and still not working.

Comment: @kh.b  Can you try with `as.Date(Date, "%d/%m/%Y")`

Comment: I have done this: 
date1=strptime(date1,"%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S")
 date1=format(date1,"%d/%m/%Y")
  date1=as.Date(date1,"%d/%m/%Y")

Comment: @kh.b  check the class of 'date1'  I think from the strptime, you could directly convert to `Date` class with `as.Date(date1)`

Comment: It  works. Thank you. I created a function to convert character to date class, I removed the line format.
`df1 %>%
    group_by(ID1) %>%
    mutate(Diff = c(NA, diff(Date)))`

Comment: @kh.b  Note that `strptime` stores objects in a `list`.  So, the `format` may have yielded some strange results.  Though, I couldn't reproduce your problem `as.Date(format(strptime("2018-01-01 05:03:02", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), "%d/%m/%Y"), "%d/%m/%Y")#
[1] "2018-01-01"`\